# Why hibernate is not deleting rows?

Tags: java, hibernate

I was going through basic of hibernate using JPA annotations and I have one question. I created one dummy project with structure as this -

One entity class person

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="personIdGenerator")
private int personIdentifier;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String title;
private String sex;

@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@javax.persistence.MapKeyColumn(name="ADDRESS_TYPE")
private Map<AddressType,Address> address = new HashMap<AddressType, Address>();
```

One Embeddable Class Address -

```
private String streetAddressLane1;
private String streetAddressLane2;
private String streetAddressLane3;

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private City city;
```

And finally one entity class City -

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int cityId;
private String city;
private String state;
private String country;
private String zipCode;
```

Now I am having one main method with code as -

```
SessionFactory sesFac = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sesFac.openSession();
     Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    // session.save(city);
     //session.save(adr);
     Person person = (Person) session.get(Person.class, 101);
    //Employee empNew = (Employee)session.merge(emp);
    //empNew.setEmpId(2);
//  System.out.println(person.getAddress().get(AddressType.HOME_ADDRESS).getCity().getZipCode());
     //Employee empOld= (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, empNew.getEmpId());
     session.getTransaction().commit();
     session.flush();
     session.close();

     session = sesFac.openSession();
      tx = session.beginTransaction();
    // session.save(city);
     //session.save(adr);
     person.setLastName("gggggg");
     session.saveOrUpdate(person);
    //Employee empNew = (Employee)session.merge(emp);
    //empNew.setEmpId(2);

     //Employee empOld= (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, empNew.getEmpId());
     session.getTransaction().commit();
     session.close();
```

Here in the main method I am getting two different sessions and two different transaction. In the first one I am getting record for person id 101, which is already there in the data base and in the second transaction i am setting last name to gggggg.

Now since I am using lazy initialization, there shouldn't be any address and city when I am trying to change the name and pass it to saveOrUpdate method. So this should delete the existing addresses assigned to the person id 101, but this is not the case. Addresses are still there and last name is getting changed to ggggg. I am unable to understand what can be the reason for this. Does hibernate created proxies handles such kind of updation or what?

Comment: I guess it is because the address is lazy loaded and you didn't change the address, so HIbernate does not handle this attribute and didn't change it.

Answer (score 1):

"Not loaded" is not the same as "deleted", and Hibernate tracks the difference on everything it loads.

In this specific case, when Hibernate loads a `Person` entity, it wraps the `address` field in a [`PersistentMap`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/collection/internal/PersistentMap.html), which initially is flagged as not yet loaded. If you were to access the `address` field and read or change anything in it, the `PersistentMap` would load its contents from the database at that time, and track that something was changed. Hibernate would then save the changes on commit.

As you do not read or change the `address` field, when Hibernate handles commit it checks the `PersistentMap`, finds it was never loaded, and proceeds to ignore it, leaving that part of the data unchanged.

If you want to clear `address` data, you will need to do so explicitly. Hibernate tries to avoid accidental changes to data, and treating something that was never loaded the same as a deletion would be very prone to accidents.

Answer (score 0):

If you close the session, the Person entity is detached. When you call `saveOrUpdate()`, hibernate will re-attach the detached object into the new Session.

To perform lazy loading, Hibernate wraps Person in a proxy class that extends Person. The initialization checks are done in this proxy. Meaning that if you never hit the database in your first session for the addresses, the proxy will know this, and when the entity gets re-attached in the second session, it will treat the addresses as uninitialized and not delete them from the database.